# REsfull API - Sending data using a get request instead of post request - what are the (security) risks?

Tags: rest, api, post

I got asked if its possible to use GET to send data instead of post and why that would be a bad idea. Ive tried to research it but cannot find any (good) answers and would be happy about an answer! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a `GET` request with a body. Any intermediate servers are allowed by [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) to ignore, discard, or modify the body of `GET` request. In addition, you may wind up violating the [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) or [idempotence](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) constraints for some requests, which would confuse intermediate servers.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by intermediate servers? Lets say I log in a user, send his credentials from client to my backend and then to my db. The body would include email and password. at what point could an 'intermediate server' modify the data.Also, 'ignore, discard' when could that practivally be the case? Thank you